# 1090mhz receiver and MySql Database

Tags: c#, mysql, ports

I have a 1090mhz receiver. What it receives its not very important right now. But you can have a look at it  [here](http://www.radargadgets.com/index.htm) . It outputs strings of hex data over a USB port. 
So far so good. What i want to do is create a c# program that will retrieve the data from the port, do a little decoding which i can handle my self and then store it in a Mysql database which is running on my pc. I have basic knowledge of c#. 
So my questions are the following :

- How can I retrieve the data from the virtual serial port using c#
- How can I store the contents of variables in to a Mysql database using c#

If possible provide any link with examples or step by step tutorials or something.

Comment: these are so unrelated that you would be better off with two questions.

Comment: I think the OP would be better off researching both those topics then coming back with specific questions. Answers to both these questions can easily be found on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reading from the serial port, check out the documentation on MSDN for the `SerialPort` class:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.aspx

For writing to MySql, I'd google for "MySql C#".  There are at least a few pages that will help you bootstrap yourself.

Or look into using a [DB ORM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) with MySql.

Comment: An ORM is a way big overkill for a task like this.

Comment: @vbence: Are there smaller/simpler yet still robust and extensible tools for creating a functional DAL?  I honestly don't have a lot of experience in this area, and would appreciate suggestions :)

Comment: OP only wants to save them, you don't need an abstraction layer to do that. Just connect to your DBMS on ODBC and send those `INSERT`s.

Comment: @vbence: I think my answer covers both options.  I was hoping you'd know a half-way alternative, but it seems we'll just have to leave it at that.

Comment: @vbence, jayt: See this question for a spectrum of DB access alternatives - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/90565/lightweight-alternatives-to-nhibernate.  Found this while looking for something else :)  Of course, like vbence said, you could simply use the ADO.net provider for MySql, or use some sort of generic ODBC connection, and have at it.